# Check if it's the front page in the template

Tags: theming, 8

Im trying to show content when I'm on the front page of my Drupal 8 test website, but the content shows on every page:

```
{% if front_page %}
  <header role="banner">
    {% if logo %}
      <a href="{{ front_page }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">
        <img src="{{ logo }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}"/>
      </a>
    {% endif %}
    <h1 style="color:black">TESTTESTTESTESTAET</h1>
<h1>test</h1

    {{ page.header }}
  </header>
{% endif %}
```

Why doesn't this work and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The variable you're looking for is called `is_front`:

```
{% if is_front %}
```

The available variables for a template are documented at the top of the .html.twig file, however there is also a set of default variables available to all templates (which are not documented in every single template). You can find them in [_template_preprocess_default_variables()](https://api.drupal.org/api/search/8/_template_preprocess_default_variables).

Comment: Thanks this one worked! is there a way to add a {{elseif}} after this if statement?

Comment: Yes, the Twig documentation has details on that: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html

Answer (score 26):

Note that if you want to provide `$variables['is_front']` to templates that doesn't, you can add this into the concerned preprocess function.

```
function themename_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  try {
    $variables['is_front'] = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $variables['is_front'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

It is done the same way in [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8.2.x) for `page.html.twig`.

Same answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183391/is-is-front-variable-available-in-menu-html-twig-template)

Comment: This was useful for me in template_preprocess_html, as "is_front" is not available by default in html.html.twig

Comment: I think you ought to add `url.path.is_front` as a cache context as well. See [this comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266902/how-to-check-if-the-page-is-front-page/266904#comment327077_266904).

Comment: It doesn't work in TWIG for a block. How do I do it in a block?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the template you are using is page.html.twig, then the variable you are looking for is `is_front`; `front_page` contains the URL of the front page, initialized in [`template_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8.2.x) with the following code.

```
$variables['front_page'] = \Drupal::url('<front>');
```

For other template files, Drupal doesn't provide any variables telling you if the user is visiting the front page. Using code similar to the one used from `template_preprocess_page()`, you can set that variable in the preprocess function for the template you are using.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables) {
  // An exception might be thrown.
  try {
    $variables['is_front'] = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    // If the database is not yet available, set the default value.
    $variables['is_front'] = FALSE;
  }  
}
```

Replace `HOOK` with the template type (e.g. *field* for the field.hmtl.twig template).

Answer (score 4):

You can get it directly in html.html.twig using root_path. It is already output on line 31 to set the body class:

**{% if not root_path %}**

CODE

**{% endif %}**

Answer (score 1):

for field template this is the code that needs to be placed in mytheme.theme :

```
        function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$vars, $hook) {
          $element = &$vars['element'];
          if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_page_paragraphs') {
            $vars['is_front'] = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();
          }
        }
```