# How to check if the page is front page?

Tags: 8

The following method not returning any value (true or false).

`\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();`

How to check if the page is front or not?

Comment: Your snippet should actually just give you what you want. Maybe you need to wrap it with a try&catch, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/204203/15055. Or you maybe need some cache buster strategy as suggested by `@Andy` in the comments to `@Kevin`'s answer below. Where exactly do you call that snippet from?

Comment: The line you are showing is correct, but there could be errors in the rest of the code. Since you aren't showing the rest of the code, we cannot tell you what is wrong, except that it is not the line you are showing, as the answers for the other question make clear.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I am trying to use it in  .module file . I am using it inside hook_page_attachments. For debugging purpose i am  using die() statement on next line . $is_front = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();
 //print($is_front); die();

Answer (score 25):

This is indeed a way to check if it is the front page and should return a value if you check the method code.

I am using it in a few preprocess hooks:

```
$variables['is_front'] = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();
```

Comment: If you do that, I think the `url.path.is_front` cache context should be added.

Comment: @Andy – Interested in how that would like like then I am.

Comment: @leymannx I believe in a theme preprocess you can set `#cache` and `#attached` on the variables array, see [`ThemeManager::render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21ThemeManager.php/function/ThemeManager%3A%3Arender/8.5.x) - if that answers your Q? ie `$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path.is_front';`

Comment: @Andy – Yeah, thanks for sharing! Will keep it in my valuable little Drupal gems box :)

Answer (score 11):

- Twig : 
  You can use `{% if is_front %}`.
  here is an example [page.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21profiles%21demo_umami%21themes%21umami%21templates%21layout%21page.html.twig/8.5.x)
- PHP: `\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();`